# Gremlin python next() not working similar to next in Gremlin Console

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune, gremlin-server, gremlinpython, neptune-python-utils

In gremlin python I'm not able to find a way to iterate through without loading everything at once in the memory.
for eg.In gremlin python ->

```
g.V().next()
```

Will iterate all the vertices in the graph at the same time
But we can iterate through the graph one at a time in gremlin console
for eg. In gremlin console ->

```
t = g.V();[]
t.next()  # V[0]
t.next()  # V[1]
```

In gremlin python the query will timeout for large enough vertices.
Is there any way in gremlin python or gremlin java to iterate through the vertices one at a time?
I have been searching for a way to do this for over a week.

I also tried https://jayanta-mondal.medium.com/the-curious-case-of-pagination-for-gremlin-queries-d6fd9518620, but it did not work.

We want a efficient way to iterate over the graph without timing out.

Comment: How big is the graph?  Are you needing to fetch all vertices?  And if so, what is the intent of doing so?  (Reason I'm asking all of this is because we just launched Neptune Analytics, which is a new feature in Neptune designed more for patterns that require computing across an entire graph).

Comment: @TaylorRiggan: I have a script which does some analytics on the graph for which I would need to load the entire graph. 
The graph should have around 38M nodes and 100M edges

Comment: You may want to look at using Neptune Analytics then, as trying to iterate over 38M vertices with a single query on Neptune Database isn't going to scale well.

Comment: @TaylorRiggan, so if I do g.V() only using neptune analytics it should be able to fetch all the 38M records at once? 
Because I would need to fetch all the edges and vertices too because my script needs all them in memory to work..

Comment: The intent of using Neptune Analytics would be to use its built-in algorithms or write a query to do the processing that you require inside of the Neptune Analytics graph.  NA supports openCypher today, so if you can express your logic in OC, then this should work well. If you want to process data outside of Neptune, the best way to fetch all of the data from Neptune DB is to use Neptune-Export (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/neptune-export.html)